# Loop help (roblox)

Tags: loops, lua, roblox

I have a problem with this script:

```
local plight = script.Parent.Bulb.PointLight
local slight = script.Parent.Bulb.SpotLight
local rotatingPart = script.Parent.Bulb

local reader = script.Parent.Parent["card-reader1a"].reader1a.ProximityPrompt
local c = 0
local cc = 0

local tweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local tInfo = TweenInfo.new(0.5, Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, Enum.EasingDirection.InOut, 0, false)

local function rotating()
    if c == 0 then
        c = 1
        local play1 = tweenService:Create(rotatingPart, tInfo, {CFrame = rotatingPart.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(0, math.rad(120), 0)})
        play1:Play()
        play1.Completed:Connect(rotating)
        c = 0
    end
end

reader.Triggered:Connect(rotating)
```

I have infinitive loop and I don't know how to stop it. I tried many methods and nothing worked. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing
`play1.completed:Connect(rotating)`

This line of code means that upon the tween's completion fire the rotating function. Effectively causing an infinite loop.
Additionally since `:Connect()` a signal doesn't yield, every time `rotating` is called, c is set from 1 to 0 almost instantaneously. Which allows all calls to pretty much bypass the debounce.

If you wish to wait until the tween is complete, try using
`play1.completed:Wait()`

Comment: @astentx: Why isn’t this an answer? It looks like one to me. It may not be correct—I don’t know—and it could _certainly_ use more explanation. But those are reasons to potentially downvote it, not delete it.

Comment: @JeremyCaney It doesn't contain any explanation why it works or should work. There may be a lot of "try xxx" answers even containing completely rewritten code, but it is hard to reuse such code or tell if it does what it is supposed to do (what? there's no description)

Comment: I've edited my post to include more information regarding why this is the probable cause of the problem, thanks for calling that out @astentx